# angularjs controller module reference loads blank page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman

I'm trying to implement the [angular-wizard](https://github.com/mgonto/angular-wizard/) module.

I have a angular app generated by yeoman. I used `bower install angular-wizard` to get the module and referenced it in my `index.html` right above the `app.js` script tag with the other modules, like angular-resource, angular-cookies etc.

The main view loads fine until I add the `mgo-angular-wizard` reference to the controller dependencies, when added the page loads blank with no errors in the console.
eg:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('merlinApp', ['mgo-angular-wizard']) // this is where everything breaks
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];
  });
```

My index.html has the following scripts included in this order:

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>

    <!-- build:js scripts/modules.js -->
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-wizard/dist/angular-wizard.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lodash (or Underscore) dependency ?

If still not working, try adding wizard directive in your html page.

Comment: I added lodash but didn't restart the server when I initially started troubleshooting, restart and cache reset worked. Good call Nish!